# Get state of select box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im doing some Ajax filtering from a SQL database, and currently im using checkboxes, which works as they should.
I have some filters that i need to get from a select box instead, and i need your help with getting the state of the select box into my function

The functions looks like this:

```
function searchOptions() {
  var opts = [];
  $checkboxes.each(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      opts.push(this.name);
    }
  });
  return opts;
};
```

HTML for checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="type1">
<input type="checkbox" name="type2">
```

HTML for select box:

```
<select>
  <option value="value1">option1</option>
  <option value="value2">option2</option>
  <option value="value3">option3</option>
</select>
```

How do i do the same with a select box? I need to check whether it's set or not, and get the value from the `<option>`
For the checkbox i use the name attribute, and i'm not quite sure that's a proper attribute for `<option>`?

Comment: I understand that by select box you mean Radio button.  And you want to get the selection status of the Radio button, is that true?

Comment: Not quite. I'm thinking about select boxes with options. Posted my HTML above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In selects you need not worry about options. The select `value` can be extracted from `select` attribute itself You could try something like this:

```
function searchSelectOptions(){

var opts = [];
$('YOUR-SELECT-CLASS').each(function(){
    if($(this).val()!=='' || typeof $(this).val()!=='undefined'){
       opts.push(this.val());
    }
    });
return opts;

};
```

**EDIT** If you've defined your options and their values doesn't have empty string (Which is the case after OP edit). You could just do:

```
function searchSelectOptions(){

var opts = [];
$('YOUR-SELECT-CLASS').each(function(){
   opts.push(this.val());
});
return opts;

};
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `typeof $(this).val()!=='undefined'`??? And following OP's edit, the default value isn't empty string

Comment: Yep, I've posted the ans before OP's edit! So wasn't sure what was his html (not even sure if he had options at all) so I posted it

Comment: Thanks :) I'll give it a go. So it should be possible to contain both the opts for checkboxes and select box in the same function?

Comment: yep why not...you could push them into same `array` if you desire

Answer (score 0):

If the default selected option is always the first one, you can check using:

```
if(this.selectedIndex != 0)
```

Where `this` refers to `select` element.

### -jsFiddle-